# $|F:H|=|F/N:H/N|$ for nonnormal $H$

Tags: group-theory

This should be very elementary, but the solution evades me. Suppose we have a tower of groups:
$$
N \le H \le F
$$
with N normal of infinite index in F, and H nonnormal of finite index in F. How one can show that 
$$|F:H|=|F/N:H/N|$$
where $|A:B|$ denotes the index of subgroup $B$ in group $A$?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the map that sends a coset $aH$ to the image of that coset under natural projection to the quotient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a set $\{a_i\}$ of representatives of the cosets of $N$ in $H$ and a set $\{b_j\}$ of representatives of the cosets of $H$ in $F$. Then prove that $\{a_ib_j\}$ is a set of representatives of the cosets of $N$ in $F$.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Of course, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will need some time to think it over.

Comment: OK, feel free to ask.