# Index of a subgroup is finite iff two given indexes are finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given that $G$ is a group, $H,K$ are two subgroups of $G$ that satisfy the relation $K\subset H\subset G$. Prove that $[G:K]$ is finite iff $[G:H]$ and $[H:K]$ are finite.

I know definitions of Coset, Index etc but cannot connect here.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462567/fh-f-nh-n-for-nonnormal-h

Comment: **Hint:** Remember that cosets are sets of elements.  Try to prove that each coset of $H$ is a disjoint union of exactly $[H:K]$ cosets of $K$.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/v/1079675_10201670441906892_1895813177_n.jpg?oh=fda6d955c7489172847cf743c0860e56&oe=5209B13E&__gda__=1376447756_7e112566c7ececf0cd0c096886e96c13) picture helps you to visualize - I used $a_m$ and it was a mistake you can take it as $b_m$.

Comment: See theorem 4.5 of section 4 of chapter I of [Hungerford's book](http://www.amazon.com/books/dp/0387905189).